# Extending Google Search Application results with using another application

Tags: android, android-studio, google-search

I work on a Android TV project which can search movies with using users choices as input, and I want to integrate it to the Google Search Application.

For example, user enters "Interstellar" to Google Search application, my application can take this input and it will show the own results in the below of the Google Search results.

Is it possbile ? Is there any api or tool for it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called App-Indexing. Google can search your app and suggest users to open your app in the search result. E.g. if you have the imdb.com app installed and you are searching for a movie on your phone, you will be able to open the app from the search results, pointing to the specific site in the app.
Check it out here: https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/

Comment: Thank you, it will be helpful